# Replacing an input element causes onchange event in Chrome only

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I've found a strange difference in behavior between Chrome and Firefox, and am wondering if anyone knows what is going on.

First, the code (see http://jsfiddle.net/pXgaE/1/ for a live example):

HTML:

```
<input id='me' onchange='func()' />
```

Javascript:

```
function func() {
    console.log( "resetting" );
    document.getElementById( 'me' ).parentNode.innerHTML = "test";
}
```

In Firefox, if I type something in the field and hit "enter", the log message appears once. On the other hand, in Chrome, the log message appears *twice*.

What is different (wrong?) about Chrome's event handling?

**Aside:** No, I don't like this code much, either, and I'd prefer to rewrite it more sensibly. But I'm really curious as to what's going on under-the-hood that would explain this.

**EDIT:** For some reason, closing input tags gets me every time. They should be properly closed now. Also, FYI, I'm getting this behavior on Chrome 30.0.1599.101 on Mac, and also on Chrome Canary 32.0.1680.0.

**EDIT 2:** I was originally setting the innerHTML to another input tag, but I can reproduce this just by setting to plain text. Update both the Javascript and the JSFiddle link.

Comment: Is this just idle curiousity as to why it triggers the event?  Or are you actually looking for a better way to do this?

Comment: chrome breaks everything, didn't you know?

Comment: Input elements don't have a closing tag.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the behaviour in chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m

Comment: @RobG Thanks, fixed. Gets me every time for some reason.

Comment: @plalx What platform are you on? I've seen this in the same version as you…

Comment: @jfriend00 Idle curiosity, I guess. Somehow it seems that there might be a "deeper" logic to Chrome's behavior than I'm seeing, and I would love to know the whole story, if there is one. As far as a a better way, I'd far rather have this particular code not remove and re-create the `input` element in the first place, which will probably fix the issue. So, yes, mostly curiosity. :-)

Comment: onChange fires when you hit enter as it should, and also when the input loses focus. onblur will only fire when the cursor leaves the input such as during a form submit, or tabbing to next input.  This will only fire once.

Comment: @carter From that, I'd expect both Firefox and Chrome to fire two events…but only Chrome gives two.

Comment: Chrome fires the extra event when you replace the input(notice if you comment out your input replacement only one event fires), which may qualify as a change.  For these edge cases often the spec is not specific enough for all browsers to implement the same policy. Welcome to the web.  :)

Comment: @carter That makes sense. I was expecting Chrome, then, to fire the event when the node was destroyed…but it doesn't in other instances. Ah, well, interesting nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: What I said in my previous comment wasn't quite correct…it depends on the dirty state of the input, as mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

With some insight from @carter and a [second test case](http://jsfiddle.net/dahjelle/6meYF/1/), I think I understand what is going on now.

The `onchange` event fires, first, for the normal put-in-new-text-and-hit-enter case. This happens in both Firefox and Chrome and is what I'd expect.

Second, in Chrome, the `onchange` event also fires if the `input` is "dirty" (i.e. has a change) and is subsequently destroyed. This does not happen in Firefox. Note that the `input` being dirty is important—if no change has occurred since the last `onchange`, there typically won't be another event sent.

Chrome has an exception to that behavior, though: if the `input` is destroyed *during* the handling of the `onchange` event, it apparently still considers the `input` dirty, and so fires a *second* `onchange` event.

You can see this by changing the Javascript above to the following:

```
function func() {
    console.log( 'resetting' );
}

setTimeout( function() {
    document.getElementById( 'me' ).parentNode.innerHTML = 'test';
}, 3000 );
```

You'll see that, if you type in the input before the replacement occurs, you'll get the log message in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: This is so strange. Just encountered it today myself, here's a minimal reproduction: https://jsfiddle.net/679btchn/ Only when removing the element from within the `oninput` does the `onchange` event get erroneously fired. This is still happening even in 2022. Has anyone filed a bug report?

Comment: Created a chromium bug about it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1297334

Comment: V. Rubinetti — thanks! I starred the issue you created. Amazing to see this come up over 8 years later! :-)